# Why can some Redis keys be searched and displayed by Redis tree view, but keys or scan commands cannot find them?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I installed RedisInsight and connected to a Redis cluster, which is in cluster mode. In the tree view, I can find and access keys `Abc:Def:v2:*`.

However, in the RedisInsight-CLI, the following command returns nothing

```
scan 0 match A* count 1000000
keys A*
```

`scan 0 match A* count 1000000` command just return

```
1) "0"
2) (empty list or set)
```

I can also delete the keys found in tree view using `del` command.

```
del Abc:Def:v2:1234
```

I tried the following command on a key

```
cluster keyslot Abc:Def:v2:1234
```

and it returns

```
(integer) 6791
```

Then I tried

```
scan 6791 match A* count 100000
```

And it returned

```
1) "0"
2) (empty list or set)
```

Comment: Just found out that `Another Redis Desktop Manager` works. `keys A*` can list all the keys starting with A.

Comment: However, running `del key1 key2 ....` (all the keys returns by 'keys` got the error of `crosslot keys in request don't hash to the same slot`?